# Create new record and commit transaction with ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to trigger an adequate PUT request when I add a new record to a one to many field using ember-data.

```
var track = genre.get('tracks').createRecord({name: "Hit me baby one more time!"})
track.get('transaction').commit()
```

This will send a PUT request to '/genres' and send all the genre attributes and other tracks as well.

```
// PUT /genres
{"genre":{"name":"Pop","tracks": [{"name":"Hit me baby one more time!","genre_id":null}]}}
```

But I would prefer sth. like:

```
// PUT /tracks
{"track": {"name":"Hit me baby one more time!", "genre_id":1}}}
```

If somehow possible I would also like to add an additional parameter automatically for PUT requests on /tracks. These are my models:

```
App.Genre = DS.Model.extend({
  name:         DS.attr('string'),
  tracks:       DS.hasMany('App.Track')
})

App.Track = DS.Model.extend({
  genre:      DS.belongsTo('App.Genre'),
  uri:        DS.attr('string')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, in the REST adapter I had this setting:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Genre', {
  tracks: { embedded: 'always' }
})
```

Setting `embedded` to `load` solved my problem.